# PHP form giving Errors

Tags: php

```
  This is my PHP code which I'm using and Error is coming between the First Echo command in the code. Can anyone please Help?
```

> ```
> <?php
>         if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
>         // Checking For Blank Fields..
>         if($_POST["name"]==""||$_POST["email"]==""||$_POST["phone_number"]==""||$_POST["city"]==""||$_POST["gre_score"]==""||$_POST["toefl_score"]==""||$_POST["eng_marks"]==""||$_POST["country"]==""||$_POST["course_type"]==""||$_POST["department"]==""||$_POST["exp"]==""||$_POST["ug_details"]==""||$_POST["pg_details"]){
>         echo "Something Went Please Try Again!";
>         }else{
>         // Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
>         $email=$_POST['email'];
>         // Sanitize E-mail Address
>         $email =filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
>         // Validate E-mail Address
>         $email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
>         if (!$email){
>         echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
>         }
>         else{
>         $name = '$name';
>         $subject = 'Registration Form';
>         $headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
>         $headers .= 'Cc:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
>         $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
>         $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
>         // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
>                   $message = '<html><body>';
>
>                   $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
>                   $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";
>                   $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
>                   $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone Number:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['phone_number']) . "</td></tr>";
>                     $message .= "<tr><td><strong>City: </strong></td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['city']) . "</td></tr>";
>                   $message .= "<tr><td><strong>GRE Score:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['gre_score']) . "</td></tr>";
>                   $message .= "<tr><td><strong>TOEFL/IELTS Score:</strong> </td><td>" .  strip_tags($_POST['toefl_score']) .
> ```
>
> "";
>                         $message .= "**Engineering Marks:** " .  strip_tags($_POST['eng_marks']) .
>   "";
>                           $message .= "**Country Planning:**  " . strip_tags($_POST['country']) . "";
>                         $message .= "**Department:** " .  strip_tags($_POST['department']) . "";
>                           $message .= "**Job Experience:**  " . strip_tags($_POST['exp']) . "";
>                           $message .= "**Under Graduation Details:** " . strip_tags($_POST['ug_details']) .
>   "";
>                           $message .= "**Post Graduation Details:**" . strip_tags($_POST['pg_details']) .
>   "";
>                         $message .= "**Course Selected:** " .  strip_tags($_POST['course_type']) .
>   "";
>
> ```
>                   $message .= "</body></html>";
>
>         // Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
>         mail("yash119ambaskar@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
>         echo "Your mail has been sent successfuly ! You will be contacted Shortly!";
>         }
>         }
>         }
>         ?>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello Syntax error in your first if condition.Your post pg_details, you have not compare it with empty string.**

```
        if($_POST["name"]==""||$_POST["email"]==""||$_POST["phone_number"]==""||$_POST["city"]==""||$_POST["gre_score"]==""||$_POST["toefl_score"]==""||$_POST["eng_marks"]==""||$_POST["country"]==""||$_POST["course_type"]==""||$_POST["department"]==""||$_POST["exp"]==""||$_POST["ug_details"]==""||$_POST["pg_details"] == ""){
```